# Filtering a WMS layer in QGIS Server doesn't accept "IN" operator

Tags: qgis, wms, filter, qgis-server

I am using OpenLayers to connects to QGIS Server, to serve a WMS layers.

I want to filter the WMS layer according to one attribute. I have followed [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/wms.html#moderate-fa-use-filter-opacities-and-styles-parameters)   to do so. Everything is working fine if I use the '=' operator, like the following, for example:

```
FILTER=myLayerName: "myAttribute" = 1
```

But I need to have the criteria using the 'IN' operator, because I am filtering on multi values, like the following, for example (doesn't work)

```
FILTER=myLayerName: "myAttribute" IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Could you please advice me with the proper way to use the  'IN' operator with Integer values?

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late, but still : I ran into the same problem and eventually found [this page](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/services.html), where it es explained that

> Text strings need to be enclosed with quotes (single quotes for strings, double quotes for attributes) A space between each word / special character is mandatory. Allowed Keywords and special characters are ‘AND’,’OR’,’IN’,’=’,’<’,’>=’, ‘>’,’>=’,’!=*,’(‘,’)’. Semicolons in string expressions are not allowed

I tried it on my own QGIS 3.4 server and I could make work something like

```
FILTER=mylayername:"attribute1" = 'value1' AND "attribute2" < 10000
```

I believe that in your case, the problem is that your query should look like :

```
FILTER=myLayerName: "myAttribute" IN ( 1 , 2 , 3 )
```

i.e. with spaces between each value / word / single character like the parenthesis.